# Kendo Grid Export To Excel Drop down list values instead of text in exported file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

when i export the grid using saveAsExcel the columns which are dropdown show me values(Guids) instead of text.
how can i show text instead of values in exported file?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an handler to the grid's "excelExport" event which fires before the export and allows you to tweak the data first.  You can loop through the rows and columns to replace the id-value with its mapping in the columns values collection.  It's brute-force but it works.  The only other, more efficient way would be to create the excel file on the server instead of the client-side processing provided by the grid, uses an optimized query that provides the text value directly.

This is the function we use.  It works on all foreign-key columns, not just enums despite the name.

```
var replaceEnums = function (e) {

    //Purpose:
    //  Convert enumeration columns to use the string value.

    var hiddenCnt = 0;
    var groupCnt = 0;
    var dataCnt = false;

    //Loop through the columns and look for a values collection. 
    for (var iCol = 0; iCol < e.sender.columns.length; iCol++) {
        //if the column is hidden then do not do the replacement
        if (!e.sender.columns[iCol].hidden) {
            //If the values collection exists that means the column is an enumeration.
            if (e.sender.columns[iCol].values) {
                //Loop through each row
                for (var iRow = 1; iRow < e.workbook.sheets[0].rows.length; iRow++) {
                    if (e.workbook.sheets[0].rows[iRow].type == "data") {
                        var cell = e.workbook.sheets[0].rows[iRow].cells[iCol - hiddenCnt + groupCnt]
                        dataCnt = true;
                        //Loop through the enumeration and get the string value.  Stop once the correct
                        //value is found.
                        for (var iEnums = 0; iEnums < e.sender.columns[iCol].values.length; iEnums++) {
                            if (e.sender.columns[iCol].values[iEnums].value == cell.value) {
                                //Replace the enum value with the string value.
                                cell.value = e.sender.columns[iCol].values[iEnums].text
                                break
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        //Track the number of group headers.  We need to track the 
                        //number of group headers because a group causes the columns
                        //to shift over by one for each grouping.
                        if (e.workbook.sheets[0].rows[iRow].type == "group-header") {
                            if (!dataCnt) {
                                groupCnt++;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            //The column is hidden so add it to the count of hidden columns
            hiddenCnt++;
        }
    }
};

grid.bind("excelExport", replaceEnums);
```

Comment: in my case i have drop downs with remote datasources, and data is not available when i export main grid for drop downs so it shows guids only.

Comment: You will have to get the guid-text mappings somehow.  You could fetch them at the beginning of the event and use them instead of the columns.values.  There's likely some other possibilities but I would not be able to explore them unless you post a dojo/jsbin with example data.

Comment: Thanks, with the help of your code i came up with a  solution and it worked!